# Let's [scrape] these tags off the bottom of our shoe

Tags: discussion, support, synonym-request, clean-up

There are so many scraping related tags right now:

- [web-scraping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/web-scraping) - 47,235 questions
- [screen-scraping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/screen-scraping) - 4,126 questions
- [scrape](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/scrape) - 1,181 questions
- <s>[scraper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/scraper) - 277</s> (as of Dec 31, 2022 is a synonym of [web-scraping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/web-scraping))

There are others that are probably okay being their own tag, but these all seem to be in dire need of cleanup.

Obviously, this is not a burnination request, because this tag is on topic, but some synonymization and cleaning up of old questions should really occur here.

Comment: I already cleaned up [tag:scraper] in July and proposed as a synonym of [tag:web-scraping]. The same goes for [tag:webpagescraping].  The problem with [tag:screen-scraping] is that many (most?) questions actually mean [tag:web-scraping].

Comment: @ArtjomB. - The wiki for screen-scraping actually says it's also known as web-scaping. I would disagree with that... screen-scraping is for scraping content from anywhere on your screen, whether it originates from a webpage or not, whereas web-scraping is for scraping content from any page, whether it's actually displayed on your screen or not. I am familiar with a few okay web-scraping tools... I've yet to find a screen-scraping tool that is particularly useful.

Comment: @ArtOfWarfare The tag needs to be separated; the ones incorrectly tagged need to be retagged, and the wiki needs to be changed to clearly reflect what it really should be.

Comment: I personally often see actual web-scraping related questions tagged as web-crawler, screen-scraping, scrape, screen-scraper. So, yes, I would say there is a confusion.

Comment: @ArtjomB That's ironic because many webpage scraping techniques don't involve rendering to a screen.

Answer (score 1):

As of Dec 31, 2022 (UTC -06:00), there are still some clean-up to do as [scrape](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/scrape) is still used and [screen-scraping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/screen-scraping) still has questions about web scraping.

---

- The excerpt of [scrape](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/scrape) is

  > DO NOT USE THIS TAG. It is under an active cleanup: [Let's [scrape] these tags off the bottom of our shoe](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/305314) Use [web-scraping] if your question is about scraping information from web resources (there is also [screen-scraping]) or use [pdf-scraping] if your question is about scraping information from pdf files. Use [data-extraction] if you need to extract data from other resources.
- The excerpt of [screen-scraping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/screen-scraping) is

  > Screen-scraping, also known as web-scraping or data-scraping, is a software technique used to collect and parse information from user interfaces. If your question is specifically about scraping from websites or web-APIs, please use the [web-scraping] tag instead.
- The excerpt of [web-scraping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/web-scraping) is

  > Web scraping is the process of extracting specific information from websites that do not readily provide an API or other methods of automated data retrieval. Questions about "How To Get Started With Scraping" (e.g. with Excel VBA) should be *thoroughly researched* as numerous functional code samples are available. Web scraping methods include 3rd-party applications, development of custom software, or even manual data collection in a standardized way.